# Update user profile photo with Microsoft Graph .NET SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a problem with updating or setting a user profile picture in Microsoft graph using the Microsoft.Graph .net SDK.

**Scenario:**

Native app with user (user role) present including a user profile page allowing the user to update his profile.

Azure AD v2.0 endpoint used & app registration done accordingly. App is used by many tenants, therefore we have Admin Consent flow included in the apps sign-up flow.

The scopes consented are `User.ReadWrite`, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, and `User.ReadWrite.All`.

---

When uploading a User profile picture using the library, we would expect the `Content-Type` to be `image/jpeg` per [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update#request-body). Fiddler however shows `content-type` as `application/octet-stream`

```http
PUT /v1.0/me/photo/$value HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.7.0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Authorization: bearer //removed//
Content-Length: 1051534
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Result is strange as I think its miss interpreted by graph

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message":
      "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., The value is set to empty\r\nParameter name: smtpAddress",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5b549f03-1ce5-4c8c-a393-27aef3ed1a75",
      "date": "2018-02-07T12:32:26"
    }
  }
}
```

The code I'm using looks like this:

```cs
if (_selectedPhoto != null)
{
    using(IRandomAccessStream raStream = await _selectedPhoto.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        await graphClient
            .Me
            .Photo
            .Content
            .Request()
            .PutAsync(raStream.AsStream());
    }
}
```

I addition I cloned the [SDK repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) and ran the Unit Test `UserUpdatePhoto` with the same negative result.

The corresponding method is below. Changing content type to `image/jpeg` does result in a `503 unknown error`. Not sure what the root cause is here.

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream> PutAsync(Stream content, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead)
{
    this.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    this.Method = "PUT";
    return this.SendStreamRequestAsync(content, cancellationToken, completionOption);
}
```

Comment: The error is reporting that `smtpAddress` is missing. To clarify, does this account have a valid (and provisioned) mailbox in Exchange Online?

Comment: You are right! We checked one of the affected mailboxes and there was an issue with its provisioning. After recreating the mailbox the call went straight through. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I’ve checked the Mailbox of an affected user and there was an issue with the mailbox provisioning. So, the issue was only due to a missing mailbox.